# Dockerfile CMD unable to locate entrypoint file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile that ends with

```
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

CMD /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

but after building the image, when I try to run it, I get

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh: not found
```

If I change the last line to

```
CMD ls -l /usr/local/bin/
```

when I run the image, I get the output

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           484 Jul 21 13:07 entrypoint.sh
```

which shows that the entrypoint.sh file is actually in the directory.
When I use docker export to export the filesystem of the container after running it, I can also find the entrypoint.sh file in /usr/local/bin/

I'm not sure what's causing the entrypoint.sh file to not be found, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Docker for Windows? This could be caused due to CRLF line breaks instead of LF when you copy the file from a Windows host to the container.

Comment: Also, what is the base image that you are using for your Dockerfile?

Comment: Can you show the contents of entrypoint.sh?

Comment: @octagon_octopus Ahh yes I was using windows, converting to LF line breaks solved the problem. Thank you soo much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using windows to write the entrypoint.sh file.

As octagon_octopus suggested, changing the line breaks of the entrypoint.sh file from CRLF to LF fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your container, but have you tried swapping CMD for ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile?

Another thing worth trying is to specify that you want to run the file with shell

`CMD ["/bin/sh", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]`

I'd suggest having a look at [this](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/#:%7E:text=In%20a%20nutshell&text=CMD%20sets%20default%20command%20and,will%20run%20as%20an%20executable.)